# Function that returns all files whose name contain a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I have a directory which contains a number of .txt files named like this:

```
factor1.txt
factor2.txt
factor3.txt
factor4.txt
factor1-factor2.txt
factor2-factor3.txt
```

Now I want to create a function, that takes a list of factor names, say `searchFiles(listOfFactorNames)`, and then returns a list of all files in this directory whose name contain at least one of the factornames specified in the list of factor names.

So for example if `listOfFactorNames=['factor1','factor4']` then `searchFiles(listOfFactorNames)` should return the list `['factor1.txt','factor4.txt','fator1-factor2.txt']`

So far I have written the following:

```
def search_for_files(listOfFactorNames,path):
    listOfFiles=os.listdir(path)
    resList=[]
    for f in listOfFiles:
        for factor in listOfFactorNames:
            if factor in f:
                resList.append(f)
    return list(set(resList)
```

This however doesn't seem very elegant and I was wondering if there is an easier/smarter way to achieve the same. Especially, last line where I remove duplicates from the resulting list.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why not just use glob?

Comment: You have a missing bracket in the line that returns.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

```
def search_for_files(listOfFactorNames, path):
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        for factor in listOfFactorNames:
            if factor in f:
                yield f
                break
```

The `break` will prevent duplicates.  And I changed the whole thing into a generator for efficiency in cases where you don't actually need a list, like:

```
for f in search_for_files(...):
    print f
```

If you do need a list, simply:

```
files = list(search_for_files(...))
```

Comment: It's not going to be great if `listOfFactorNames` has many entries, but it is easy to read and it's a generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `glob` to help you out here:

```
import glob
import os

def find_matching_files(patterns, file_dir):
   matches = []
   for pattern in patterns:
      search_path = os.path.join(file_dir, '*{}*'.format(pattern))
      for match in glob.iglob(search_path):
         matches.append(match)
   return matches
```

Call it like this:

```
i = find_matches_files(['factor1', 'factor2'], '/home/some/dir')
```

To prune duplicates, convert the *result* to a set:

```
i = set(find_matches_files(['factor1', 'factor2'], '/home/some/dir'))
```

You can optionally change the method as well:

```
def find_unique_matching_files(patterns, file_dir):
   matches = set()
   for pattern in patterns:
      search_path = os.path.join(file_dir, '*{}*'.format(pattern))
      for match in glob.iglob(search_path):
         matches.add(match)
   return matches
```

Comment: Do note that `matches` could contain duplicates, so perhaps converting it to a `set` would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
def search_for_files(patterns, path):
    return [os.path.join(path, name)
        for name in os.listdir(path)
            if any(pattern in name for pattern in patterns)
    ]
```